# How to use GenericArray?

Tags: rust

In the Rust code below, I cannot convert my array of bytes into a GenericArray. The compiler tells me to give a type the "bytes"  like  `generic_array::GenericArray<u8, N>`, but I don't know what to use as "N".

I found out the N must be of type ArrayLength and I am stuck here because I don't see the link with a size to pass.

```
fn main() {

    use aes::block_cipher_trait::generic_array::GenericArray;

    let phrase = "Le Rust tu comprendras jeune padawan !";

    println!("my phrase {:?}", &phrase);

    let b = phrase.as_bytes();

    println!("my bytes {:?} len : {}", &b, b.len());

    let bytes = GenericArray::clone_from_slice(&b[0..16]);

    println!("my bytes {:?}", &bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`aes::cipher::generic_array` is just a copy of [the crate `generic_array`](https://docs.rs/generic-array/latest/generic_array/index.html), so it's worth perusing the documentation there.

The second type parameter in `GenericArray<T, N>` represents in some sense the length of the `GenericArray`. `generic_array` uses the types from the crate `typenum` by default (though with some effort, you could provide your own types — you'd just need to implement the necessary traits for them).

Much like how `aes` provides `generic_array` as a public dependency, `generic_array` has a copy of `typenum` in its tree, so you can use its types like so:

```
fn main() {
    use aes::cipher::generic_array::{typenum::U16, GenericArray};

    let phrase = "Le Rust tu comprendras jeune padawan !";

    println!("my phrase {:?}", &phrase);

    let b = phrase.as_bytes();

    println!("my bytes {:?} len : {}", &b, b.len());

    let bytes: GenericArray<_, U16> = GenericArray::clone_from_slice(&b[0..16]);

    println!("my bytes {:?}", &bytes);
}
```

[(playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c1610db23fe61feeabc01d6b9b37a075) Note that I used `generic_array` directly. The playground doesn't have the `aes` crate.)

Here, we've used `typenum::U16` since we want an array of length 16.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the neat answer!

Comment: this just shows how to use clone_from_slice. i don't think that's why this question is popular. people want to know how to go from an array [u8;32] to a GenericArray and the like.